# Lifecycle aware AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-lifecycle

Is there a way to create a utility class or extension for `AlertDialog` that is `LifeCycle` aware? Thus having the possibility of window leak can be completely avoided? Handling of dialog dismissal on each usage cause repetitive code/boilerplate.